# Is it ok to use Google+ / Google Plus SDK in iPhone App in production?

Tags: iphone, ios

Am asking this because I see a note in https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/ saying :

Note: We are launching the Google+ platform for iOS initially in Developer Preview. This means that you can test and run your applications, but not yet go into production.

Does it mean that we are not supposed to, yet, integrate G+ into iPhone App? Or is there any other approved way to do it , as of now?